# Winforms list view, anchoring the columns with the form?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listview

this sounds like a really simple question but could easily have a very complicated answer knowing listviews but I basically just want it so that the column width inside a list view will expand as I expand the application window, essentially the same way as anchoring the listView itself?

If I'm not being clear please comment and I'll try explaining better.

My only guess at the moment would be setting the columns to have percentage widths that relate to the listview's size?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes you can do this by modifying the columns with when the form is resized. You will need to anchor the ListView on the form to start with:

```
Private Sub Form1_Resize(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Resize
    With ListView1
        .Columns(0).Width = CInt(.Width * 0.2) 'set column width to be 20% of controls width
        .Columns(1).Width = CInt(.Width * 0.5) 'set column width to be 50% of controls width
    End With
End Sub
```

Be careful though that you don't end up with column widths that total more than 100% due to rounding as this may give undesirable results